# How to get Angular list [Object] values

Tags: javascript, angular

- Hi, I would like to get each object value with arrays.

**example:**

```
   let stockValues:any;
   stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);
       for(var i=0;i<stockValues.length;i++){
       console.log(stockValues[0]); //here I need to get index 0 of value of '2' but object values showing
      }
```

> expected out-put :2

Comment: you are using typescript so use this and dont use the any type

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate **forEach** loop here is the ex:

```
 stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);
 stockValues.forEach(data => { 
     console.log(data);  // here you will get the 2,3,4 ... 
 })
```

i hope it helps you out

Answer (score 1):

```js
let stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);
stockValues.forEach(c=> console.log(c))
```

You can use forEach like this

```
stockValues.forEach(c=> console.log(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just find the index of the given element then you can use this

```
 let stockValues:any;
   stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);
       for(var i=0;i<stockValues.length;i++){
           if(stockValues[i] == 2){
            console.log(i);
            break;
           }
      }
```

This will print out 0 as the index of 2 is 0

If you want to print out the whole elements, then use this.

```
let stockValues:any;
       stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);
           for(var i=0;i<stockValues.length;i++){

                console.log(stockValues[i] );

          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

Here you will get both key as well as value also.

```
let stockValues= Object.values([2,3,4,5]);

 stockValues.forEach((value,key) => { 

    console.log("Key = "+key);

    console.log("Value = "+value);

 });
```

I hope this will be useful.